# Converting member function pointer to string

Tags: c++

I have a class which consists of a function. I just need to call this function periodically. One timer callback api is there which is of the form mentioned below:

```
Timer(&obj,&Class::Func,Time)
```

So if we attach the member function to this api, it will be called periodically.

There is a wrapper for this api which accepts arguments as string. So I need to pass every argument as string and do the necessary parsing and call the actual api.

So I want to first convert the object address and member function address to string and use it in my project. Can anyone help me by giving sample code to do this.

Comment: _"So I want to first convert the object address and member function address to string and use it in my project."_ That won't work at all.

Comment: I tried this -> http://cpp.sh/9map , compiles with warning though

Comment: A little more context would help. What is the design idea behind a wrapper which calls functions "by name"? Can you perhaps tell the wrapper beforehand which string maps to which function, like `void MapFunctionToID(Class::Func, string)`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a member function to string and then use it at all.

There is a few way to convert a type or an expression to a string, like [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), but it works only in this way, not in the opposite.

There is just no native way in C++ to convert a string to a member function address. However, you can make an associative container (like a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)) associating strings to member function pointers, and use it for wrapping and unwrapping.